# JPA with eclipse link not loading child records for first time

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Hi I have one table  VariantValidityBE
It has a relationship column like this

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "variantValidityBE", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<VariantValidityValueBE> variantValidityBEList;
```

And in another table

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   private VariantValidityBE variantValidityBE;
```

And my method  is like this

```
    List<VariantValidityBE> resultList = getResultList(VariantValidityBE.FIND_ALL); 
for (VariantValidityBE variantValidityBE : resultList) {
  List<VariantValidityValueBE> options = variantValidityBE.getVariantValidityBEList();
 }
```

the value of option is coming old value, newly inserted child record is not coming

Values are inserted into DB correctly.

But if I restart the application its giving the updated records.

The same type of relations I used so many times, never get such type problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since JPA entities are treated as regular java objects, you are required to keep both sides of bidirectional relationships in synch with each other when making changes.  JPA will not perform magic to mirror changes made to one side of a bidirectional relationship to the other for you.  So when you add a new VariantValidityValueBE instance and set its variantValidityBE, you must also add the VariantValidityValueBE to the variantValidityBEList.  Otherwise, the variantValidityBEList will remain unchanged and stale until it is refreshed from the database.

Comment: Hi chris, I got the solution  I added getEntityManager().refresh(variantValidityBE);
then its loading child records..

Comment: This will cause a database hit for each and every variantValidityBE in your list.  You might want to add the eclipselink.refresh query hint to your initial query so that all VariantValidityBE get refreshed up front in a single query, or a better solution is to set both sides of your relationship when creating the new VariantValidityValueBE, as then you do not need the refresh at all, allowing the cache to be used.